# Plotting multiple data in barplot using ggplot in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which I would like to count the number of tanks with a given heat loss. In addition, I need to distinguish between tanks which has a heating coil those that do not and whether the heating coil is active all year or only in the summer.

A sample of my dataframe looks like this:

```
sample.df <- data.frame(
  NumberOfTanks = c(1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1),
  ElectricalSupport = c("None", "Summer","Summer","Always","None","Always","Summer","Always","None","Always","None", "Summer"),
  HeatLoss = c(0.50,1.20,2.0,0.50,1.20,2.0,0.50,1.20,2.0,0.50,1.20,2.0),
  BFactor = c(0,0.5,0.7,1,1,0.7,0,0.5,0.7,1,1,0.7)
  )
sample.df <- sample.df[order(sample.df$BFactor),]
```

I tried the following code, which gives me the number of tanks with a given heat loss for all tanks

```
ggplot(sample.df, aes(x=HeatLoss, y=NumberOfTanks, fill=factor(BFactor)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,3,0.2))
```

[image]

Now I would like to distinguish further, such that I have three bars for each "HeatLoss" corresponding to one for each "ElectricalSupport" (i.e. "None", "Summer" or "Always).

I find that many recommend reshaping the dataframe into "long" format, in questions similar to mine; however, as I need to count the number of tanks (which is given in a separate column), I don't know if that is possible.

Many thanks in advance,

/Morten

Comment: add `+facet_wrap(~ElectricalSupport)` doesn't help?

Comment: It could provide a solution, but it gives me the bars in two separate graphs; I would like them to be in the same graph (preferably with different colors, using a gradient of that color as fill).